# How to deploy Lambda as container image for multiple functions with shared libs

Tags: aws-lambda

I am confused about deploying AWS Lambda as container image when there are multiple functions with shared libs.

One way is to package all the functions and the shared libs into a single image. For each function, the same image is used while the handler in CMD is different. The disadvantage is that updating a single function code will cause the container image to be updated, hence all Lambda functions will also be updated. As the number of functions increases, the deployment time also increases. According to my experience (using CDK), the deployment duration is about 7-8 minutes if there are ~100 functions.

The other way is to package each function as individual image. However, it will occupy a lot of ECR storage if there are many functions. For example, a base image of nodejs is about 100MB in size, so 100 functions will be about 10G!

The usage of layer seems to solve the dilemma. However, as far as I know, the layer is only suitable for Lambda deployed as .zip.

Comment: Maybe create a "god" function that calls other functions so that you have a single CMD? Like the way some CLI tools work.  Seems like a bad idea worth exploring.

Comment: I'm not sure if ECR charges for the nominal volume of every image, but shared layers don't take up extra storage space if they are used in more than one image